# discord.py returns input with ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hey'

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot that will take input and store it in a int variable for later writing it into a text file:

```
@client.command()
async def createproject(ctx):

    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.message.author
    
    await ctx.send("This is a test")
    msg = await client.wait_for("message", check = check, timeout = 30)
    desc = int(msg.content)
    await ctx.send(desc)
```

The bot succesfully sends the "This is a test message" and it had ran flawlessly untill this error

The error code specified is:

```
File "c:/Users/data/Desktop/discord bot/main.py", line 101, in createproject
    desc = int(msg.content)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hey'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\data\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\data\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\data\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hey'
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 9, you tried to change the `msg.content` to integer with `desc = int(msg.content)`. But if a message includes a non numeric letter, then this error will raise. If you just want to get integer messages, you can use `str.isdigit` function. You can check it:

```
msg = await client.wait_for("message", check = check, timeout = 30)
if msg.isdigit():
    desc = int(msg.content)
```

So your code should seem like:

```py
@client.command()
async def createproject(ctx):

    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.message.author
    
    await ctx.send("This is a test")
    msg = await client.wait_for("message", check = check, timeout = 30)
    if msg.isdigit():
        desc = int(msg.content)
    else:
        await ctx.send('Please type numbers only')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! For anyone wondering how to make it into a str the code is as it follows:  `@client.command()
async def createproject(ctx):

    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.message.author
    
    await ctx.send("This is a test")
    msg = await client.wait_for("message", check = check, timeout = 30)
    desc = str(msg.content)
    await ctx.send(desc)
`